# pandas new data frame from list elements

Tags: pandas, list

I have a data frame

```
col1 col2 col 3 …col n
```

I have to do all possible combination between all columns and do the chisquare test of independence.

```
    import researchpy

    for i in range (0, len(corr_data.columns)):
    
        for j in range(0, len(corr_data.columns)):
        try:
            
            col1 = corr_data.iloc[:,i]
            col2 = corr_data.iloc[:,j]
#         print(col1.info())
#         print(col2.info()) 
            crosstab, res = researchpy.crosstab(col1, col2, test= "chi-square")
            #print(res)
            r1 = res.values.tolist()
```

the result(res) is like this

```
    `                         0          1
    0  Pearson Chi-square ( 9.0) =   20322.0
    1                    p-value =       0.0
    2                 Cramer's V =       1.0`
```

I want to create a dataframe so that it has cramers value p value and chisquare value listed as follows

```
            col 1           col 2         col 3  .......    col n 
        col 1  20322.0
               pvalue:0
               cramer's v:1.0    
    
    col 2
    
    col 3
    
    ....
    
    
    col n
```

I tried this code but stuck at it. Any help will be appreciated.

```
        m = np.asarray(r1)
        g1 = pd.DataFrame(m)
        
        Chi_square = g1[0].values
        P_value = g1[1].values
        Cramers_V = g1[2].values
        print(g1[2][0])
       
        corr_mat = pd.DataFrame(index = range(0, len(corr_data.columns)), columns=range(0, len(corr_data.columns))) 

        
        for k in range(0, len(corr_data.columns)):
            
            for l in range (0, len(corr_data.columns)):
                row = int(g1[2][1])
    
                col = int(g1[2][1])
                 if (row != 99999 and col != 99999):
                    corr_mat[col][row] = Cramers_V[k]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
import pandas as pd
import researchpy as rp
import numpy as np
import itertools


# set seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(922020)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size= (101, 4)),
                  columns= ['disease', 'severity', 'alive', 'status'])


def it_chi(data):
    
    # creates a list of all possible column combinations
    combs = list(itertools.combinations(data.columns.to_list(), 2))

    cols = [c[1] for c in combs]  # creating a list for column labels
    ix = [c[0] for c in combs]    # creating a list for index labels
    
    series = [] #empty list for results
    
    for comb in combs:
        table, res = rp.crosstab(data[comb[0]], data[comb[1]], test = 'chi-square')
        

        
        series.append({res['Chi-square test'][0]: res['results'][0],
                       res['Chi-square test'][1]: res['results'][1],
                       res['Chi-square test'][2]: res['results'][2]})
    
    # np.diag() creates a matrix with the diag filled in and 0s elsewhere
    frame = pd.DataFrame(np.diag(series), 
                         columns = cols,
                         index = ix)
    
    return frame


it_chi(df)
```